# Android WebView.addJavascriptInterface() any restrictions?

Tags: android, webview

is interface passed to javascript via

```
WebView.addJavascriptInterface()
```

restricted in some way?

I mean, what if i do

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(sms,"SMSManager");
```

then in javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Send SMS" onClick="sendSMS()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendSMS() {
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
</script>
```

will javascript trigger sending SMS?
Would that mean that javascript can use any application privileges, specified in application manifest, as long as passed object allows it?

Any help appreciated,

thanx Matej S.

Comment: Good question, I look forward to seeing what the answer is lol.

Comment: Sorry but if you think it is stupid question, i would appreciate if u told me why... :/

Comment: I wasn't sarcastic, I was actually being sincere! I have the same question.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work ok. Usually it's better to create a custom object that exposes exactly what operations that you want the WebView to have access to. I have built one that exposed the phone's vibration feature (which requires a permission) for example. Also be careful about what kind of objects are in the signature to the methods that you want to be able to invoke from JavaScript. You probably want to stick to primitives and arrays, and be careful with Booleans.